# html extract header and footer to separate documents

Tags: php, html, templates, insert

I have several html documents which share the same header and footer and would like to extract header and footer to separate html files and include them to other html documents.

The idea is very simple: when I change something in header, the change has to be made on all pages.

Until now I used PHP include function. But I have read some articles that this has impact on performance.

What is the best way to do this for clean html pages ?

Is the PHP the way to go ?

If it is, should I insert the whole html content into PHP echo ?

Comment: You can use <php include "header.html";  ?> Or you can use require instead of include which will get the header but if not found the page will fail to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a good way doing it in pure HTML, since iframe or an ajax-request using Javascript wouldn't be a good solution here.

I would say the best way is to use the PHP include or PHP require-function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

You won't see any performance issues. Remember that include is a little bit faster than include_once, since include_once will have to make an extra check if the file has already been included.

Answer (score 0):

You want to include header in all html pages, so php include is better.
no need of echo, just create a header.html(or any html file).
Then use

```
  <?php
    include "header.html";  //or name of your headerfile
   ?>
```

add this php code to all your pages.Thus all pages will point to same header file, and i dont think it will affect performance. Same idea for footer too :)